# PrettyTable library is not working when using official source code from GitHub

Tags: python, python-import, prettytable

I am getting this error when using the prettytable library on my virtual machine.

```
File "lib_report.py", line 7, in <module>
from prettytable import PrettyTable
File "/users/ssri/Documents/prettytable.py", line 137
self._field_names: list[str] = []
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help me fix this issue?

I downloaded the prettytable.py file from the official GitHub repo and tried using it in my code.

Comment: It seems like you are using python version < 3.6. Type annotation was introduced in Python 3.6